# RestKit how to map an array inside an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20, restkit-0.24.x

Here's the response:

```
{
  "status": true,
  "statuscode": 200,
  "result": [
    {
      "name": "ABC",
      "date": "2015-01-30",
      "documents": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "doc1",
          "status": "complete",
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "doc2",
          "status": "complete",
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "doc3",
          "status": "complete",
        }
      ],
      "message": "Hello World",
      "status": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to map and get only all the "document" inside an array keyed "result" and I don't need anything with other objects / mappings. I just need the documents. How can that be done / declared in the response descriptors to automatically match all these documents to my managed object?

Comment: What did you try? What didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Try This :-

```
NSDictionary *dic=@{
                    @"status": @true,
                    @"statuscode":@ 200,
                    @"result": @[
                            @{
                                @"name": @"ABC",
                                @"date": @"2015-01-30",
                                @"documents": @[
                                        @{
                                            @"id":@ 1,
                                            @"name": @"doc1",
                                            @"status": @"complete",
                                            },
                                        @{
                                            @"id":@ 2,
                                            @"name": @"doc2",
                                            @"status":@ "complete",
                                            },
                                        @{
                                            @"id":@ 3,
                                            @"name": @"doc3",
                                            @"status": @"complete",
                                            }
                                        ],
                                @"message": @"Hello World",
                                @"status":@ 3
                                }
                            ]
                    };
```

I am storing your response in NSDictionary and get it by -

```
 [[[dic objectForKey:@"result"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"documents"]
```

change your indexNumber as require !

Comment: this answer has nothing to do with restkit

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];  //From Server you will get response data in form of NSData , so the 'responseData' is a type of NSData
NSArray *appDetais = [jsonData objectForKey:@"result"];
NSDictionary *resultJsonData = [appDetais objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *documentDetailsArray = [jsonData resultJsonData:@"documents"];
for(int i=0;i<[documentDetailsArray count];i++){
   NSDictionary *singleDocumentDetail = [documentDetailsArray objectAtIndex:0];
   NSLog(@"%@",[singleDocumentDetail objectForKey:@"id"]);
}
```

You may try this.. :)

Comment: this answer has nothing to do with restkit